# Oraagent many SYSRAC processes open

Tags: oracle, clustering, rac

I see in my 19c Cluster database a lot of sessions (over 350) with SYSRAC user and status INACTIVE with oraagent.bin TNS V1. They can consume my connection pool (how can I make this bigger number).

Why do I see so much those inactive connections and if this is realy so needed? Could this be some PL/SQL dbms monitoring metrics for the Oracle Cloud Control?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

These are internal, background processes connecting Oracle RAC Database with Oracle Grid Infrastructure High Availability Services. You can't control them. The status of "INACTIVE" can be misleading; it doesn't mean they don't have a purpose or aren't actually doing anything. Any background or user session will show as "INACTIVE" unless it is actually performing an operation that takes long enough to be recognized from one monitoring cycle to the next, at the *exact* moment you happen to query gv$session.

What "connection pool" are you trying to grow? These background processes should not count against most application-level pools or limits.

Comment: Hi.The issues is that I had to make a scheduler task to killl inactive session from sysrac (6 hours or more idle) because they made the database closed for other sessions, because the PGA processes limit was reached pretty soon.

Comment: Have you opened a service request with Oracle Support? That many sessions (depending on the size of your RAC) could be a bug.

Comment: Yes I did. I need to patch the complete stack , so I will use the fix as temp solution, to kill the idle sessions every 5 hours.